# powershell - inline variable replace

Tags: powershell

I have a SQL script that contains statements such as the following:

```
CREATE GROUP $MyGroup;
CREATE USER $MyUser;
```

Is there a way using Powershell that I can echo out the file contents with those variables replaced with their current values as set previously?

So if I had previously issued:

```
$MyGroup = 'group';
$MyUser = 'user';
```

the resultant string, after reading the file contents and substituting the variables, would be:

```
CREATE GROUP group;
CREATE USER user;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, through the `$ExecutionContext` you can access the `ExpandString` function:

```
$fileContents = Get-Content myfile.sql
$ExecutionContext.InvokeCommand.ExpandString($fileContents)
```